# Replace Partial File Name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, replace, rename

I have been working to rename all files within a folder that are older than 5 days within PowerShell.

The file names all read as:

```
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd & WBS - 20140313
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd & WBS - 20140314
```

etc.
Occasionally there will be some slight anomalies such as:

```
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd & WBS - 20140316 - do not use
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd & WBS - 20140314 (AutoSaved)
```

Now I want simply to remove the " & WBS " from each of the files (all saved in excel format so the files would be)

```
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd- 20140313
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd- 20140314
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd- 20140316 - do not use
XTYPE  -to-  CoOrd- 20140314 (AutoSaved)
```

Now my code so far I believe is near enough there...

```
$myFolder = '\\iiGlasgow.co.uk\public\Controls\Archived Files\'
ForEach ($File in Get-Childitem $myFolder | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime   -lt (get-date).AddDays(-5)})
```

So I have set the folder and advised PowerShell to only deal with items over 5 days old.

I cannot get it to replace the partial string elements however...  Its probably really simple I just can't see it.  I've scoured the internet and tried all sorts of iterations but it is not happening.

So my final elements which I believe to be the closest to a solution then read...

```
{
$myFile = $file.name
$myFullFilename = $file.FullName
$myRenamed = $myFile.Replace(" & WBS ","") 
}
```

The script in its entirety for ease?

```
$myFolder = '\\iiGlasgow.co.uk\public\Controls\Archived Files\'
ForEach ($File in Get-Childitem $myFolder | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime   -lt (get-date).AddDays(-5)})
{
$myFile = $file.name
$myFullFilename = $file.FullName
$myRenamed = $myFile.Replace(" & WBS ","") 
}
```

Your help and pointers at my mistakes are as ever massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would extend the `Where-Object` cmdlet and filter all basenames containing `& WBS`. Then just rename the file using the `Rename-item` cmdlet:

```
$myFolder = '\\iiGlasgow.co.uk\public\Controls\Archived Files\'
Get-Childitem $myFolder | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-5) -and $_.BaseName -Match ' & WBS ' } | 
    Foreach {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace ' & WBS ')
    }
```